# How could this be modeled from a database perspective?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a model Project, which has a start date and an end date. A project can have multiple objectives, and each objective should have a status ( succesful or not ) for every day.

So, for example, let's say I have a project named `"Get in better shape"`, which starts today, and ends in 1 month. I add the following objective `"Run 1 km"`. For every day of the project I want to mark the objective as succesful or failed. I was thinking that the result should be a different model, belonging to objective. Roughly, I have this:

```
Project   has_many   :objectives
Objective belongs_to :project
          has_one    :result
Result    belongs_to :objective
```

The thing is, I was also thinking of maybe adding the Day as a model, because right now it feels very complicated to show a certain day ( and it's results ) ... but somehow it wouldn't feel right.

Is there a simpler way of representing the models? How are you handling apps where date ranges are relevant/important ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was working on something similar recently. You can set it up like this:

```
Project     has_many     :objectives
Objective   belongs_to   :project
            has_many     :result
Result      belongs_to   :objective
```

Then use `cron` to create entry in `Result` database each day. Rails sets up timestamps in database by default, so filter results for a certain day by using `created_at` field.

You can use [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem to set up cron jobs.